# ALT in Firefox defocuses input fields for a split second

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys, firefox

To type Polish letters I need right <kbd>Alt</kbd> with a letter, for example <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> gives "ą" but pressing any <kbd>Alt</kbd> deselects input fields for a split second.

This happens only in Firefox on my Ubuntu 17.10, Unity. On the same system this doesn't happen on Opera, for example, or any other program.

The final result is that in Firefox it may, depending on the page:

- not register the pressed letter
- select all input and replace with the Polish letter
- move back part of the text (for example till the last emote in Messenger) and insert the Polish letter there

For example when I click on "Search on Ask Ubuntu..." on the header of this page, then click any <kbd>Alt</kbd>, I see that my typing cursor disappears for a split second every time I click the key.

As you see this is annoying. I'd like to continue to use Firefox instead of other browsers because of Firefox location bar search (I type a few more or less associated words and this almost always finds what I want in the history).

I tried with no result:

- unbinding Alt from Keyboard > Shortcuts
- disabling all addons in Firefox

What I use that may be related:

- Ubuntu 17.10
- Firefox 59.0.2 (but it's been this way for several months)
- Compiz with shortcuts (no single <kbd>Alt</kbd> shortcut)
- Guake (no shortcut on <kbd>Alt</kbd>)

Do you have any idea how to solve it? Thanks in advance!